# how to append data to json in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Say i have this short code:

```
item = Item.find(params[:id])
render :json => item.to_json
```

but i needed to insert/push extra information to the returned json object, how do i do that?

Lets say i need to insert this extra info:

```
message : "it works"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
item = Item.find(params[:id])
item["message"] = "it works"
render :json => item.to_json
```

Comment: Wouldn't this line throw and error : item["message"] = "it works" .
As far as I know you can not add properties dynamically like this in ruby ( you could do something like this in js though ) .

Comment: This would work, but only if item was/is a hash. You can dynamically add properties to hashes.

Comment: Does ActiveRecord return a hash ?

Comment: I try it but I got error `can't write unknown attribute`. But below solving is works for me.

Comment: How would this look if you were trying to append a collection?  
  
`items = Item.all`   

`items["message"] = "it works"`       

`render json: items.to_json`    

throws a 'no implicit conversion of String into Integer' error

Comment: I think `item = item.as_json` need add to second line? haven't test yet

Answer (score 14):

The `to_json` method takes an [option object as parameter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001364) . So what you can do is make a method in your item class called as message and have it return the text that you want as its value .

```
class Item  < ActiveRecord::Base
 def message
  "it works"
 end
end

render :json => item.to_json(:methods => :message)
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the accepted answer now throws deprecation warnings in Rails 3.2.13.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `message'.  Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use`attr_writer` etc.

Assuming you don't want to put the suggested attr_writer in your model, you can use the `as_json` method (returns a Hash) to tweak your JSON response object.

```
item = Item.find(params[:id])
render :json => item.as_json.merge(:message => 'it works')
```

Comment: `as_json` returns an array and there's no method called `merge` for array.
there's a way to convert the item object into hash and then simply add the `:message`. such as

`render json: Hash[[*item.map.with_index]].invert[:message] = 'it works'`

converting into hash
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330612/convert-array-to-hash-while-preserving-array-index-values-in-ruby)

Comment: or there's another solution.
just add item object into a hash, like
`render json: {items: item, message: 'it works'}`

Comment: ActiveModel's as_json method [returns a Hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json).

Comment: @the_ousek It only returns an array of hashes if there is more than one result for you query. So for the particular example Steve was describing it would have indeed returned a hash because it only returns one value.

Answer (score 1):

## How to append data to json in ruby/rails 5

If you use scaffold, e.g.:

```
rails generate scaffold MyItem
```

in the view folder you will see next files:

```
app/view/my_item/_my_item.json.jbuilder
app/view/my_item/index.json.jbuilder
```

so, you can add custom data to json output for an item, just add this:

```
json.extract! my_item, :id, :some_filed, :created_at, :updated_at
json.url my_item_url(my_item, format: :json)    

json.my_data my_function(my_item)
```

As you can see, it's possible to modify as one item json output, as index json output.

Answer (score 0):

I always use:

```
@item = Item.find(params[:id])
render json: { item: @item.map { |p| { id: p.id, name: p.name } }, message: "it works"  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this ?

```
item = Item.find(params[:id]) 
item <<{ :status => "Success" }

render :json => item.to_json
```