# Convert Array to Hash while preserving Array index values in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array that has `X` number of values in it. The following array only has 4, but I need the code to be dynamic and not reliant on only having four array objects.

`array = ["Adult", "Family", "Single", "Child"]`

I want to convert `array` to a hash that looks like this:

`hash = {0 => 'Adult', 1 => 'Family', 2 => 'Single', 3 => 'Child'}`

The hash should have as many key/value pairs as the array has objects, and the values should start at 0 and increment by 1 for each object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
Hash[array.each_with_index.map { |value, index| [index, value] }]
# => {0=>"Adult", 1=>"Family", 2=>"Single", 3=>"Child"}
```

As @hirolau commented, `each_with_index.map` can also be written as `map.with_index`.

```
Hash[array.map.with_index { |value, index| [index, value] }]
# => {0=>"Adult", 1=>"Family", 2=>"Single", 3=>"Child"}
```

**UPDATE**

Alterantive that use [`Hash#invert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert):

```
Hash[array.map.with_index{|*x|x}].invert
# => {0=>"Adult", 1=>"Family", 2=>"Single", 3=>"Child"}
Hash[[*array.map.with_index]].invert
# => {0=>"Adult", 1=>"Family", 2=>"Single", 3=>"Child"}
```

Comment: Awesome, that does it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: each_with_index.map can also be written as map.with_index, just a tad nicer.

Comment: Hash[array.map.with_index{|*x|x}].invert

Comment: @hirolau, Thank you for comment. I added your suggestion.

Comment: @hirolao, thanks for that.  I see there's also `with_object`.  Much nicer to put those after the Enumerable method.

Answer (score 7):

Another one:

```
Hash[array.each_index.zip(array)]
#=> {0=>"Adult", 1=>"Family", 2=>"Single", 3=>"Child"}
```

Newer Ruby versions would allow:

```
array.each_with_index.to_h.invert
#=> {0=>"Adult", 1=>"Family", 2=>"Single", 3=>"Child"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Hash[*(0..array.size-1).to_a.zip(array)]
    => {0=>"Adult", 1=>"Family", 2=>"Single", 3=>"Child"}
```

Comment: Nice! We can make it even shorter - `Hash[(0...array.size).zip(array)]`

Comment: Very good, @Alex. Thanks for the tip.  I tend to avoid three dots in ranges (except when golfing)--too easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
array.each_with_index.inject({}){ |hash, (val, i)| hash[i]=val; hash }
=> {0=>"Adult", 1=>"Family", 2=>"Single", 3=>"Child"}
```