# Convert an Array of Strings to a Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an Array that contains strings:

`["First Name", "Last Name", "Location", "Description"]`

I need to convert the Array to a Hash, as in the following:

`{"A" => "First Name", "B" => "Last Name", "C" => "Location", "D" => "Description"}`

Also, this way too:

`{"First Name" => "A", "Last Name" => "B", "Location" => "C", "Description" => "D"}`

Any thoughts how to handle this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
arr = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Location", "Description"]

letter = Enumerator.new do |y|
  l = ('A'.ord-1).chr
  loop do
    y.yield l=l.next
  end
end
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007f9a00878fd8>:each> 

h = arr.each_with_object({}) { |s,h| h[letter.next] = s }
  #=> {"A"=>"First Name", "B"=>"Last Name", "C"=>"Location", "D"=>"Description"} 

h.invert
  #=> {"First Name"=>"A", "Last Name"=>"B", "Location"=>"C", "Description"=>"D"}
```

or

```
letter = ('A'.ord-1).chr
  #=> "@" 
h = arr.each_with_object({}) { |s,h| h[letter = letter.next] = s }
  #=> {"A"=>"First Name", "B"=>"Last Name", "C"=>"Location", "D"=>"Description"}
```

When using the enumerator `letter`, we have

```
27.times { puts letter.next }
  #=> "A"
  #   "B"
  #   ...
  #   "Z"
  #   "AA"
```

Comment: very nice use of `Enumerable#next` and inversion (of which I completely forgot about).

Comment: Cary, one more question. What's the easier way to retrieve a value from the hash using the above code?

Comment: @NicholasAlek this seems like a question that might benefit more from self discovery by looking at the `Hash` object. There are many methods for retrieval all are very easy.

Comment: I think the second solution (while still viable) might get confusing when you reach the end of the alphabet and start getting characters like `"["  "\\"  "]"  "^"`, etc. the last solution is by far the best and I would upvote again if possible just for that.

Comment: I have a dilemma. Perhaps I should either update this question or post a new question. Anyhow, I'll ask it here for the time being. The array comes from a table column. So if I remove "Last Name" as part of the array, I should be getting "C" assigned as oppose to "B" to "Location". Any thoughts on this perhaps?

Comment: @engineersmnky, note that `'Z'.next => 'AA'`. The Ruby monks are looking out for us.

Comment: @CarySwoveland How do you persist letters per value? For example, if I remove "First Name", I shouldn't see "A" as part of the arr. Equally, if I remove "Location", I shouldn't see "C" but the rest remain as is.  Basically, the arr comes from the table's column and when it's updated, some of those values will not be part of the arr any more. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nicholas, I'm not sure I understand your question. If `h = {"A"=>"First Name", "B"=>"Last Name", "C"=>"Location", "D"=>"Description"}` and `h.delete("A")`, then `h #=> {"B"=>"Last Name", "C"=>"Location", "D"=>"Description"}`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: @engineersmnky, I don't follow.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, my initial question should have been framed around Rails as well as Ruby. Anyhow, I was hoping to map letters to a column in table where each value is associated with its letter. So, when a user updates a record in a table column, whether to delete it or create a new one, letter assigned remains, meaning letters persist on update and create. I am not sure if this is possible to do it without creating an extra column for letters, which in my case is easier. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Nicholas, I don't know Rails, so "updating a record in a table column" is not within my expertise. Perhaps someone else can answer this (@engineersmnky, perhaps?).

Comment: @NicholasAlek ask a new question then with a bit more description and I would be glad to assist.

Comment: @engineersmnky. I'll post  a separate question regarding the behavior without having an extra column in the table, such as letters, but mapped to some constance in a module. In the meantime, I've gone and created a new column in the table with letters. This way I know I would have persistent relationship between names and letters assigned.

Comment: @engineersmnky, just posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948981/how-to-map-an-extra-data-using-constance-to-a-column-in-the-table-that-persist

Comment: I cleaned up the construction of the enumerator. (@engineersmnky: of possible interest.)

Answer (score 2):

You could implement as follows

```
 def string_array_to_hash(a=[],keys=false)
    headers = ("A".."Z").to_a
    Hash[keys ? a.zip(headers.take(a.count)) : headers.take(a.count).zip(a)]
 end
```

Then to get your initial output it would be

```
 a = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Location", "Description"]
 string_array_to_hash a 
 #=> {"A"=>"First Name", "B"=>"Last Name", "C"=>"Location", "D"=>"Description"}
```

And second output is

```
 a = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Location", "Description"]
 string_array_to_hash a, true 
 #=> {"First Name"=>"A", "Last Name"=>"B", "Location"=>"C", "Description"=>"D"}
```

**Note:** this will work as long as `a` is less than 27 Objects otherwise you will have to specify a different desired output. This is due to the fact that a) the alphabet only has 26 letters b) Hash objects can only have unique keys.

Comment: How can I do it without creating a method?

Comment: @NicholasAlek you could just define the alphabet as `alphabet = ("A".."Z").to_a` and then abstract `a.zip(alphabet.take(a.count))` and `alphabet.take(a.count).zip(a)` to get your 2 desired results although I am not sure why you are opposed to a method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not being specific about keys name then you could try this out

```
 list = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Location", "Description"] 
 Hash[list.map.with_index{|*x|x}].invert
```

Output

```
 {0=>"First Name", 1=>"Last Name", 2=>"Location", 3=>"Description"}
```

Similar solutions is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19330628/1228901).

Comment: Thanks hkumar, it needs to have alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Or..You also can try this :)

```
letter = 'A'
arr = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Location", "Description"]
hash = {}
arr.each { |i|
hash[i] = letter
letter = letter.next
}

// => {"First Name"=>"A", "Last Name"=>"B", "Location"=>"C", "Description"=>"D"}
```

or

```
letter = 'A'
arr = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Location", "Description"]
hash = {}
arr.each { |i|
hash[letter] = i
letter = letter.next
}

// => {"A"=>"First Name", "B"=>"Last Name", "C"=>"Location", "D"=>"Description"}
```