# Non-deprecated way to set JSON attribute for model

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to set an arbitrary attribute for rendering to JSON.

I had followed the answer in this question: [how to append data to json in ruby/rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146980/how-to-append-data-to-json-in-ruby-rails/3147036#3147036) to do

```
model = Model.find
model[:extra_info] = "More detail."
model.to_json
```

It works perfectly, but in my tests I'm getting a deprecation warning that setting arbitrary attributes is no longer supported, use attr_writer.

I tried using

```
model.write_attribute(:extra_info, "More detail.")
```

which works in unit testing, but on the server, raises an exception:

```
private method `write_attribute' called for Model
```

What's the non-deprecated clean way to do this.

I'm aware I could set it in the JSON call with methods as in [Add virtual attribute to json output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892044/add-virtual-attribute-to-json-output), but in this case the variable to be added is not part of the models concern, so it doesn't have access to the data needed to construct the extra attribute, and it would be nasty and messy  to do so.

So what's the correct way for the controller to get this data pushed into the model so the JSON renders properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Model` model, put

```
attr_accessor :extra_info
```

Then in controller

```
model.extra_info = "more detail"
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, that works, but doesn't that break separation of concern with model and controller?
The attribute I'm setting is purely to do with the context that the controller is using it in and as a convenience when converting it to json to be passed through.

It seems odd that I have to inform the model that it's going to be used in that way.

Comment: So the extra info has nothing to do with the model object it's being attached to? Would it make more sense then to do this in controller: `render json: {model: model.to_json, extra_info: 'more detail'}`

Comment: Possible. But currently the `model[:extra_info]` is happening in a helper, would be nice to keep it there.
BTW, where is the ability to do `render json: { ... extra_info: ... }` documented?

Comment: Sort of [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-json). So it automatically calls to_json, and I'm just passing it a hash instead of an Active Record object

Comment: Thanks Nick. This is the second revision to the app, the first revision was passing around Hashes instead of Active Records - but it got clumsy, now that I'm more experienced with rails, I much prefer using it's "native" way of doing things where ever possible to keep the code maintainable and easy to understand.
I think for now I'm going to go with `s.send(:write_attribute, :extra_info, "more detail")` - a little bit of a hack, but produces cleanest code.

Answer (score 0):

Nick's answer above is the best in terms of creating well structured, well documented code.

**Update**
**It seems I was wrong on the below**

The code below still creates deprecation warnings on my development server.

In this particular case, I don't want to clutter the model up with extra accessors for very specific once off cases, so I'm using

```
s.send(:write_attribute, :extra_info, "more detail")
```

Inside a helper, inside the controller.