# Rails - How to add a custom attribute to json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I have File class (named as Arquivo, portuguese) in my project, and file has name attribute, it's a big name with some tag's, identifiers and the 'real name" at the end. So I need to create a new custom param at my json @files to send only the "real name"

Name example:

`CODE-ALM-TAG-TT-TAG-1122-COD12-realNameFile.txt`

I already try the anwser of this [almost duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146980/how-to-append-data-to-json-in-ruby-rails) but here he include the same param `message: "it works"` in all elements of array, and I need a diffente param for each element

I already did something that works but it's ugly, I think that has an easier way to do it:

```
def all_files
  files = Arquivo.all.as_json(include: [:tag])
  files = add_cut_name(files)
  render json: { files: files }
end

def add_cut_name(files)
  files.each do |file|
    file["cut_name"] = file["nome"].split('-')[7]
  end
  files
end
```

I am thinking in something like this:

```
def all_files
  files = Arquivo.all.as_json(include: [:tag], cut_name: ["nome"].split('-')[7])
  render json: { files: files }
end
```

But this didn't work

Comment: If `nome` is always at the end, then I would suggest `split('-').last` instead of `split('-')[7]`. That way, if `split` ever results in more than eight elements (these things happen - formats change, someone adds a new element to the file name, etc.), you'll still get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [merge](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge):

```
 files = Arquivo.all.as_json(include: [:tag]).map { |file| file.merge(cut_name: file['nome'].split('-')[7])}
```